# vb.net SendKeys.Send does not send () symbol from textbox.text

Tags: vb.net

i try to send symbol Through text box when i send (10%)+(20%) to notepad
the result 10+20 !not (10%)+(20%)
this is the code i use

```
SendKeys.SendWait("TextBox1.Text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) the plus sign, percentage symbol and parentheses have a special meaning in the context of SendKeys. You need to enclose those symbols in curly braces.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{(}10{%}{)}{+}{(}20{+}{)}")
```

You could use the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) method to do the mapping for you, e.g. text.Replace("+", "{+}") etc.

Comment: thanks MR I add TextBox1.Text = (TextBox1.Text.Replace("(", "{(}")) and worked but is thier any easy way cuz i i will send symbol from textbox

Answer (score 0):

If you read [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) you find:

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}).

So you have to change your text to be:

```
SendKeys.SendWait({(}10{%}{)}{+}{(}20{%}{)})
```